# blackberry java maps

Tags: blackberry

my program didnt showing the map. when i invoke the Blackberry maps, then its showing a pin mark with white background. its not showing the map, its only showing the locations as pin points. how i get the map ?

Comment: did u get this on device or on simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the connection,
also make sure the location is supported: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/11/blackberry-maps-revamped/